# Phantomjs authentication with node.js to access mean.js page

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, phantomjs, meanjs

I need to access a mean.js web site page with phantomjs.  The problem is I dont know what to include in the header to make it happen.

I can authenticate using http.request and get back the user object.  But then I need to somehow take that information and place it in the phantomjs header to allow access to the page.

Here is some code:

```
'use strict';

var phantom = require('node-phantom-simple');

phantom.create({ path: require('phantomjs').path }, function (err, browser) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  else {
    browser.createPage(function (err, page) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else {

//this is wrong - does not work with mean.js/passport authentication
        var authentication_data = { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer('<user>:<password>').toString('base64') };

        page.set('customHeaders', authentication_data, function (err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
          else {

            var htmlPath = 'http://localhost:3000/path-to-my-web-page';

            var complete = false;

            page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
              console.log('Console: %s', msg);
              if (msg === 'the page is loaded') complete = true;
            };

            return page.open(htmlPath, function (err, status) {
              console.log('opened page ', status);
              if (err) {
                console.log('page.open', err);
              }
              else {
                console.log('opened ' + htmlPath);
//stuff happens here after page is loaded
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I am missing the piece that says it is ok to access the page.

Thanks for your help!